# Check ListView Position inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. which are both part of a `Fragment`.

in order to capture to prevent that the `ScrollView` will affect the scrolling of the `ListView` I added the following code:

```
    myListView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        } 
    });
```

right now they both work file, I can scroll all the way down to my `ListView` and when I can see my `ListView` I can scroll within it.

my problem right now is that if I scroll to the top of my `ListView` I can't scroll backup if I keep scrolling on the `ListView` I need to hit some part of the `ScrollView` to be able to go back.

What I want to do is to check if the scrolling of `ListView`is at the top then I will be able to enable or disable the `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` and allow the `ScrollView` to take over.

I tried many options, getting the `v.getScrollY()`, `v.getY()`, `event.getY()` but all are not giving me if I'm at the top of my list. also the `myListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` has not given me the right check.

Answer (score 0):

Nice trick with setOnTouchListener.
One thing which I know exacly is that puting a listView in ScrollView is a very bad practice and google doesn't recommend to do it. You should change your layout. Try to avoid ListView inside ScrollView. ListView always sets focus on its parent, that's why it can't scroll.